# In GNU C, deos main thread invoke constructor?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

In GNU C, deos main thread invoke constructor?

I make the libhello.so library file using the hello.c file and run the main.c file using GCC.
The result is that printing thread id in hello.c constructor and thread id main function is same.

Is this a right feature?
I couldn't find the exact information on the internet.

```c
// hello.c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__((constructor)) func(void)
{
    uint64_t thread_id = pthread_self();
    printf("in constructor, thread id: %lu\n", thread_id);

    return;
}

void hello(void)
{
    printf("hello\n");

    return;
}
```

```c
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <hello.h>

void *start_routine(void *arg)
{
  hello();
  return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
  uint64_t thread_id = pthread_self();
  printf("in main function, thread id: %lu\n", thread_id);

  uint64_t new_thread_id;
  pthread_create(&new_thread_id, NULL, start_routine, NULL);

  pthread_join(new_thread_id, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions that are marked with the constructor attribute are called by the C runtime when the (shared) object that contains them is loaded and initialized. For the process executable and all libraries that are directly linked to it, this happens *before* `main` is entered, and by happenstance happens in the same thread, which will ultimately be used to invoke `main`.

For shared objects / dynamic libraries that are loaded at runtime using `dlopen`, the static constructor functions usually are invoked by the same thread that makes the `dlopen` call.

Note that this is all by happenstance and not set in stone! Implementers may in the future dispatch the execution of constructors to separate threads and in the calling thread just wait for the result.